# How to convert html string to plain text without html tags in google app script?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm new to google app script.

I was trying to convert html string to plain text without html tags in google app script using the [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57117272/is-there-a-function-or-example-for-converting-html-string-to-plaintext-without-h) in this question.

However, when I try to apply it to my script, it is not working as expected.

This is the script that I use:

```js
function toStringFromHtml(html)
{
  
html = '<div>' + html + '</div>';
html = html.replace(/<br>/g,"");
var document = XmlService.parse(html);
var strText = XmlService.getPrettyFormat().format(document);
strText = strText.replace(/<[^>]*>/g,"");
return strText;
}
```

and this is the output:
[image]

While my actual expectation is in the third column.

Can someone tell me what is wrong with my previous script?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, for example, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
return strText;
```

#### To:

```
return strText.trim();
```

#### Reference:

- [trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim)

Answer (score 1):

If you're running in a browser, then the easiest way is just to let the browser do it for you

```
function stripHtml(html)
{
   let tmp = document.createElement("DIV");
   tmp.innerHTML = html;
   return tmp.textContent || tmp.innerText || "";
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response. I tried using this and I got the error. Then I modify it a bit, and it's still error. Is this expected?

The function that I use:
function stripHtml(html)
{
  html = '<div>' + html + '</div>';
  html = html.replace(/<br>/g,"");
  var document = XmlService.parse(html);
  let tmp = document.createElement("DIV");
  tmp.innerHTML = html;
  return tmp.textContent || tmp.innerText || "";
}

Comment: what was your error ? could you share it for me pls, you got a error? i guess you should've added full code of your problem , if you can post the code of the part of the problem i could help you better

Comment: @Ninja -- is there a way to create a dummy HTML document for this purpose, so I can debug and run it on my desktop?