# How to convert a paragraph html string to plain text without html tags in google app script?

Tags: csv, google-apps-script, spreadsheet, workday-api

this is a follow up question from my previous question. I'm having trouble when I want to convert HTML strings to plain text without HTML tags in google app script using the reference in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69792726/how-to-convert-html-string-to-plain-text-without-html-tags-in-google-app-script) question. However, this time it's a paragraph format.

This is the script that I use:

```html
function pullDataFromWorkday() {
  var url = 'https://services1.myworkday.com/ccx/service/customreport2/[company name]/[owner's email]/[Report Name]?format=csv'; //this is the csv link from workday report
  var b64 = 'asdfghjklkjhgfdfghj=='; //this is supposed to be our workday password in b64
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: 'Basic '+ b64
      }
  });

//Parse   
  if (response.getResponseCode() >= 200 && response.getResponseCode() < 300) {
    var blob = response.getBlob();
    var string = blob.getDataAsString();
    var data = Utilities.parseCsv(string, ",");

    for(i=1;i<data.length;i++)
    {

      data[i][0];
      data[i][1];
      data[i][2]=toStringFromHtml(data[i][2]);
      data[i][3]=toStringFromHtml(data[i][3]);
      data[i][4]=toStringFromHtml(data[i][4]);
      data[i][5]=toStringFromHtml(data[i][5]);
    }

  //Paste  it in   
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  sheet.clear();
  sheet.getRange(1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);
    }

  else {
    return;
    }
  }



function toStringFromHtml(html)
{
  
html = '<div>' + html + '</div>';
html = html.replace(/<br>/g,"");
var document = XmlService.parse(html);
var strText = XmlService.getPrettyFormat().format(document);
strText = strText.replace(/<[^>]*>/g,"");
return strText.trim();
}
```

This is the sample of the data that I want:

[image]

Or you can use this [sample](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GuY2O-ZADXUGZ4ly6bE_u3aqVqDnkalNzIG8aEyByq8/edit?usp=sharing) spreadsheet.

Is there any step that I miss or I do wrong?

Thank you before for answering the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, how about modifying `toStringFromHtml` as follows?

#### Modified script:

```js
function toStringFromHtml(html) {
  html = '<div>' + html + '</div>';
  html = html.replace(/<br>/g, "").replace(/<p><\/p><p><\/p>/g, "<p></p>").replace(/<span>|<\/span>/g, "");
  var document = XmlService.parse(html);
  var strText = XmlService.getPrettyFormat().setIndent("").format(document);
  strText = strText.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, "");
  return strText.trim();
}
```

- In this modified script, your following sample HTML is converted as follows.

  - From

    ```
      <p><span>Hi Katy</span></p>
      <p></p>
      <p><span>The illustration (examples) paragraph is useful when we want to explain or clarify something, such as an object, a person, a concept, or a situation. Sample Illustration Topics:</span></p>
      <p></p>
      <p></p>
      <p><span>1. Examples of annoying habits people have on the Skytrain.</span></p>
      <p><span>2. Positive habits that you admire in other people. </span></p>
      <p><span>3. Endangered animals in Asia. </span></p>
    ```
  - To

    ```
      <div>
        <p>Hi Katy</p>
        <p></p>
        <p>The illustration (examples) paragraph is useful when we want to explain or clarify something,
          such as an object,
          a person,
          a concept,
          or a situation. Sample Illustration Topics:</p>
        <p></p>
        <p>1. Examples of annoying habits people have on the Skytrain.</p>
        <p>2. Positive habits that you admire in other people. </p>
        <p>3. Endangered animals in Asia. </p>
      </div>
    ```
  - By this conversion, the following result is obtained.

    ```
      Hi Katy

      The illustration (examples) paragraph is useful when we want to explain or clarify something, such as an object, a person, a concept, or a situation. Sample Illustration Topics:

      1. Examples of annoying habits people have on the Skytrain.
      2. Positive habits that you admire in other people.
      3. Endangered animals in Asia.
    ```

#### Note:

- When your sample HTML shown in your question is used, the modified script can achieve your goal. But, I'm not sure about your other HTML data. So I'm not sure whether this modified script can be used for your actual HTML data. Please be careful about this.

Comment: Hi @tanaike thank you so much for this! Now it's working fine. I modify the script a bit by removing the "replace(/<span>|<\/span>/g, "")" because not all the the raw data written in "<span></span>" apparently

Comment: @Nadila Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this library: [cheerio for Google Apps Script][1]

```js
function htmltotext() {
  let html = `<p><span>Hi Katy</span></p><p></p><p><span>The illustration (examples) paragraph is useful when we want to explain or clarify something, such as an object, a person, a concept, or a situation. Sample Illustration Topics:</span></p><p></p><p></p><p><span>1. Examples of annoying habits people have on the Skytrain.</span></p><p><span>2. Positive habits that you admire in other people.   </span></p><p><span>3. Endangered animals in Asia. </span></p>`
  const $ = Cheerio.load(html)
  let paragraph = []
  let lines = $('p')
  for(let i = 0; i < lines.length;i++) {
    let line = lines.get((i))
    let line_text = $(line).text();
    if(line_text) {
      paragraph.push(line_text)
    }
  }
  Logger.log(paragraph.join('\n'))
  return paragraph.join('\n')
}
```

Comment: Could you provide more information on what this package is, what it does and how it helps the OP?

Comment: Cheerio is a library for GAS help user can parse html.

Comment: @Tyler2P Please check last comment. I've updated my script